# Bing Ads API Reporting Data with Ruby error : 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bing, bing-api

I'm working on Bing Ads API Reporting Data using Ruby and I'm using  [bing_ads_api_Gem](https://github.com/arambert/bing_ads_api)  in order to complete the task.

```
require 'bing_ads_api'

client = BingAdsApi::Api.new(
    {
        :authentication => {
            :method               => 'ClientLogin',
            :developer_token      => 'developer-token-goes-here',
            :user_nam e           => 'username-goes-here',
            :password             => 'password-goes-here',
            :customer_id          => 'customer-id-goes-here',  
            :customer_account_id  => 'account-id-goes-here' 
        },
        :service => {:environment => 'PRODUCTION'},
        :library => {:log_level   => 'DEBUG'}
    })

# select the service and the API version (:v7 or :v8)
administration_service = client.service(:AdministrationService, :v8)
# send your request
result = administration_service.get_assigned_quota()
```

**SOAP Request in XML Format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="https://adcenter.microsoft.com/v8" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header>
      <wsdl:DeveloperToken>developer-token-goes-here</wsdl:DeveloperToken>
      <wsdl:UserName>username-goes-here</wsdl:UserName>
      <wsdl:Password>password-goes-here</wsdl:Password>
      <wsdl:CustomerId>customer-id-goes-here</wsdl:CustomerId>
      <wsdl:CustomerAccountId>account-id-goes-here</wsdl:CustomerAccountId>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <wsdl:GetAssignedQuotaRequest xmlns="https://adcenter.microsoft.com/v8" />
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

As I'm not obsessed with only single gem so tried with [other Gems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=bing%20ad)
as well.

**Do let me know if anyone need more info on this.**

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Your developer token , username or password are wrong?

Comment: @@p4sh4 No!! I got **developer-token** using _https://developers.bingads.microsoft.com/Account_ , **Username** is mailed by `Bing-ads` and as i able to login using browser so **Password** It can't be wrong!!!

Comment: I merged a few pull requests today at https://github.com/arambert/bing_ads_api, could you give it a try (point to the master branch) and tell me if it's working now ?

Comment: @Adrien Sure I'll try.

Comment: @Adrien Now its throwing error `undefined method set_header`, And its work well in sandbox but not in Production ENV